# Replace observations and create a new variable with the mutate function

Tags: r, database, dplyr

I am trying to create a new variable that contains a substitution of where is "NA", "A", "Q", "T" in the variable Var1 by 0 until line 143 and leave the others analyzed as they are normally, of the lines 144 through 164, and after line 164 assign 0 in the other letters "A", "Q", "T", using a mutate function from the dplyr package. However, I am not getting what I wanted.

```
Dados1 <- data.frame(Var1 = c(rep("NA", 60), 
c(rep("H", 20), c(rep("Q", 30),c(rep("A", 33),
c("V","R","S","T","U","V","S",
"R","S","T","U","V","S",
"T","U","S","R","V","V","B"),
 rep("NA", 30))))))
Dados1
library(dplyr)

Dados1 <- Dados1[c(1:143,),c(164:193,)] %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(NewCode = ifelse(x == c("NA","H","Q","A"), "0"))
Dados1

> Dados1 <- Dados1[c(1:143,),c(164:193,)] %>% 
+   dplyr::mutate(NewCode = ifelse(x == c("NA","H","Q","A"), "0"))
Error in c(164:193, ) : argumento 2 está vazio
```

Comment: I'm going to suppose this is *not* C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
Dados1 <- Dados1 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(NewCode = ifelse(Var1 %in% c("NA","H","Q","A"), "0",Var1))
```

Output:

```
Dados1
    Var1 NewCode
1     NA       0
2     NA       0
3     NA       0
4     NA       0
5     NA       0
6     NA       0
7     NA       0
8     NA       0
9     NA       0
10    NA       0
11    NA       0
12    NA       0
13    NA       0
14    NA       0
15    NA       0
16    NA       0
17    NA       0
18    NA       0
19    NA       0
20    NA       0
21    NA       0
22    NA       0
23    NA       0
24    NA       0
25    NA       0
26    NA       0
27    NA       0
28    NA       0
29    NA       0
30    NA       0
31    NA       0
32    NA       0
33    NA       0
34    NA       0
35    NA       0
36    NA       0
37    NA       0
38    NA       0
39    NA       0
40    NA       0
41    NA       0
42    NA       0
43    NA       0
44    NA       0
45    NA       0
46    NA       0
47    NA       0
48    NA       0
49    NA       0
50    NA       0
51    NA       0
52    NA       0
53    NA       0
54    NA       0
55    NA       0
56    NA       0
57    NA       0
58    NA       0
59    NA       0
60    NA       0
61     H       0
62     H       0
63     H       0
64     H       0
65     H       0
66     H       0
67     H       0
68     H       0
69     H       0
70     H       0
71     H       0
72     H       0
73     H       0
74     H       0
75     H       0
76     H       0
77     H       0
78     H       0
79     H       0
80     H       0
81     Q       0
82     Q       0
83     Q       0
84     Q       0
85     Q       0
86     Q       0
87     Q       0
88     Q       0
89     Q       0
90     Q       0
91     Q       0
92     Q       0
93     Q       0
94     Q       0
95     Q       0
96     Q       0
97     Q       0
98     Q       0
99     Q       0
100    Q       0
101    Q       0
102    Q       0
103    Q       0
104    Q       0
105    Q       0
106    Q       0
107    Q       0
108    Q       0
109    Q       0
110    Q       0
111    A       0
112    A       0
113    A       0
114    A       0
115    A       0
116    A       0
117    A       0
118    A       0
119    A       0
120    A       0
121    A       0
122    A       0
123    A       0
124    A       0
125    A       0
126    A       0
127    A       0
128    A       0
129    A       0
130    A       0
131    A       0
132    A       0
133    A       0
134    A       0
135    A       0
136    A       0
137    A       0
138    A       0
139    A       0
140    A       0
141    A       0
142    A       0
143    A       0
144    V       V
145    R       R
146    S       S
147    T       T
148    U       U
149    V       V
150    S       S
151    R       R
152    S       S
153    T       T
154    U       U
155    V       V
156    S       S
157    T       T
158    U       U
159    S       S
160    R       R
161    V       V
162    V       V
163    B       B
164   NA       0
165   NA       0
166   NA       0
167   NA       0
168   NA       0
169   NA       0
170   NA       0
171   NA       0
172   NA       0
173   NA       0
174   NA       0
175   NA       0
176   NA       0
177   NA       0
178   NA       0
179   NA       0
180   NA       0
181   NA       0
182   NA       0
183   NA       0
184   NA       0
185   NA       0
186   NA       0
187   NA       0
188   NA       0
189   NA       0
190   NA       0
191   NA       0
192   NA       0
193   NA       0
```

Comment: Suppose I got the same letters from 1: 143, from 144: 163 and after line 163 however I want these to be zero only from 144 to 164. How can I do that?

Comment: @BrenoG. Try in a new line `Dados1$NewCode[144:164]<-'0'`

Comment: Thanks @Duck!!!!!!!